# Reacting to the setting of variables

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans

I have a class with six properties and a change date.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

   private Long id;

   private String title; // if changed, update lastChanged

   private String subtitle;

   private Text summary; // if changed, update lastChanged

   private Text description; // if changed, update lastChanged

   private Text otherText;

   private List<Text> reviews; // if changed, update lastChanged

   private Date lastChanged;

   // Getters and setters

}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "text")
public class Text {

   private Long id;

   private String content;

   private int typeCode;

   // Getters and setters

}
```

(This is a massively simplified version of our actual domain model obviously, but it illustrates the basic problem)

The requirement is: If 'title', 'summary', 'description' or 'reviews' changes, set 'lastChanged' to the current date.
Background: These fields are relevant to an external API. My customer wants to know, which products had changes made to they API-relevant fields since date X.

I've tried to meet the requirment by implementing Hibernate Interceptors and Hibernate Event Listeners. They both did not work as I had hoped. When I change 'summary' for example, Hibernate just tells me: The field 'content' has changed in the table 'text'.

This information is not very useful, because I still don't know if 'summary', 'description' or 'otherText' has been changed. Therefore I don't know, whether or not I need to update 'lastChanged'.

My other ideas:

- Take the id of a changed Text object and try to find the products connected to it via SQL. This would propably work, but it's quite an ugly solution and it will get really complex with our domain model.
- Implement the update logic in the variables setters. Two problems with this: Hibernate calls the setters while loading objects from the database (which should not lead to updating the timestamp of course) and it does not solve the problem described above. If the setter of 'content' gets called, then what? I do not know, which property of product has been changed.

Are there any elegant solutions to this problem?

Comment: Would you like to know the changes attribute of entity?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. Do you want to know, if I need the actual value changes (what was the old value and what is the new value)? That would be nice, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the change notification problem in a generic way is not trivial, especially if you need a stateful mechanism that does not send out notifications blindly - so that e.g. changes originating from certain parts of the infrastructure do not trigger notifications.

The specifics of your problem might also simplify or complicate the issue. For example, can the same `Text` object be referenced by more than one fields of a `Product` object? In the same vein, is it possible for it to be shared among different `Product` objects? If either of those is possible, then you would have do decide what the proper course of action is when a shared object is changed - e.g. do you notify all interested parties?

One of the basic design patterns for building a notification infrastructure is the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You could use this approach to have all `Product` objects observe changes in all the `Text` objects that they reference.

If this approach is too complex or slow for your purpose, you might want to rethink your architecture. For example, would it make sense to make the `Text` class immutable? Or, if each `Text` object is only referenced by a single other object, would it be possible to add an extra field in `Text` to point to its parent object, along with a suitable constructor?

As for avoiding bogus notifications, there are a couple potential solutions:

- Restrict access to the setters to reserve them for use by any persistence/serialization mechanisms and use a different set of methods for the rest of your system. E.g. you could do something like this:

  public class Text {
      long privateId;
      ...
      private setPrivateId(long x) {
          privateId = x;
      }

  ```
  public setId(long x) {
     setPrivateId(x);

     this.triggerChangeNotifiers();
  }
  ...
  ```

  }
- Have Hibernate fill in the fields directly, without going through the setters - I believe there are a bunch of annotations for that, but keep in mind that this approach could make future refactoring much harder.